# ANTLR 3.5.2 matches rule even though input has extra tokens

Tags: java, parsing, syntax, antlr3

I am writing a grammar to parse sql statements. I have the following rule:

```
show_databases :
    SHOW DATABASES { System.out.println("Showing databases");    
;
```

When my input is `show databases`, I get the message. However, when my input is `show databases now`, I DO see the message. I am building a REPL and all of the lines end with `;`. I want to get an error since the syntax is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the end of input as well:

```
SHOW DATABASES ';'
```

or

```
SHOW DATABASES EOF
```

The way you have it, parser has no idea there cannot be "now" later as part of another statement. In fact, it stops when it matches the rule successfully and doesn't even look at the next token if it doesn't need to.

Comment: I just edited the question, but I am reading in 1 line at a time and all of my lines end with ';'.

Comment: Then match the semicolon as well, instead of `EOF`.